# Serilog to different sink, minimum level override

Tags: serilog

Using Serilog, I want to log to two different sinks: console and AzureTableStorage.

In Console I want to log everything.

In AzureTableStorage I want to log INFO and upper from my app and WARNING and upper from any other source.

How should I configure the Serilog section in appsettings to achieve this?